# C - given a case-insensitive file path, how to check whether the file exists or not?

Tags: c, file, io, case-insensitive

For example, suppose we have a file called "Hello.txt", then checking if "hello.txt" or "heLLo.txt" exist should both return true.

Comment: make a list off all possible versions of the string with different capitalization. return true on first match, else return false. it will likely not be fun, i would look for examples on google or using a library.

Comment: Read all the files in the folder/directory and perform a case insensitive compare.

Comment: That may work in principle, @r3wt, but it quickly become infeasible as the length of the input increases.

Comment: And it really becomes infeasible if more than mere existence checks are expected to be done.  How do you operate on ***A*** file if more than one matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running Windows or any case-insensitive filesystem, then there's nothing to do but check one casing. If `"Hello.txt"` exists, then `"hEllo.txt"` exists (and is the same file) (the difficult problem here is when you want to make sure that the file is spelled with a given casing in the filesystem)

If you're running a case-sensitive filesystem, just take directory name of the current file, list file contents, and compare entries against the current filename, ignoring case.

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach.  It may be a bit more complicated than that, however, if the input is permitted to have directory segments that must also be compared case-insensitively.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Yes, in that case, you have to start from root directory and locate the directory/directories matching the case of the current path. But that potentially means recursion if there are more than 1 match for each dir.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [fcaseopen](https://github.com/OneSadCookie/fcaseopen), which demonstrates how to handle case insensitive file operations.

Essentially, the C headers/functions to use are:

- From `dirent.h`, use `opendir`/`readdir`/`closedir` to go thru the files in a directory
- From `string.h`, use `strcasecmp` to compare two filesnames, ignoring the case of the characters